# "Была пять" или "было пять"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "В школе у меня была пять по алгебре" или "В школе у меня было пять по алгебре"?

Answer (score 3):

**В школе у меня было пять (баллов) по алгебре.** Сравнить: В школе у меня была пятерка (сущ. ж. р.) по алгебре.

В общем случае при подлежащем, выраженном количественно-именным сочетанием,  сказуемое может иметь формы как ед.числа,  так и мн. числа, причем **в единственном числе счетному обороту приписывается значение среднего рода**. **Вошло семь человек погони.**.. (Лесков).

Пять (в данном случае) – это пять баллов, сказуемое также ставится в форме ср. рода ед.ч.

Comment: Пример-то не шибко корректный. Мало ли что там Лесков написал. "Вошло семь человек" – это норма?

Answer (score 3):

> Как правильно:
>
> *"В школе у меня **была** пять по алгебре"*
>
> или
>
> *"В школе у меня **было** пять по алгебре"*?

Правильно:

> *В школе у меня **было** пять по алгебре.*

Правильным будет и вариант с определением:

> *В школе у меня **было твёрдое пять** по алгебре.*

В данном употреблении ***пять*** — несклоняемое **существительное среднего рода**.

Такое значение слова ***пять*** отмечается и в словарях.

См. *"Большой универсальный словарь русского языка" под ред. Морковкина (М., 2016):*

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Slava, а такой пример: В гостиной пробило девять. Здесь девять - это числительное или существительное (по Морковкину)? У  Розенталя числительные не переходили в существительные: Если в роли подлежащего выступает имя числительное без существительного, т.е. в значении абстрактного числа, то сказуемое ставится в единственном числе, например: Двадцать делится на четыре без остатка. Но если с числительным связано представление о конкретном деятеле, то употребляется форма множественного числа сказуемого, например: И опять идут двенадцать, за плечами ружьеца... (Блок).

Answer (score 1):

Правильно второе: "былО (**что** у меня былО в школе?) пять по алгебре",
но можно было бы сказать и так:
"былА (какая оценка у меня была по алгебре в школе?) **оценка** пять".

Comment: Хотелось бы обоснований. Почему "пять" - было?

Comment: @Мимоходов, методом исключения. Была? не подходит. Был?! – ещё краше.

Answer (score 0):

У всех баллов существует второе (оценочное) лицо — от единицы, двойки, и далее по порядку все — женского рода.

Говоря *пять*, выписывая это слово на бумаге, мы подразумеваем пятёрку (сущ. ж. р.). Поэтому и в разговоре, и в форме прямой речи, вариант «*была "5" по алгебре*» равно приемлем, как и литературный — «***было "пять" по алгебре***», где числительное *5* записано  словом ср. р. (в кавычках, разумеется, так как является оценкой).